# Read Excel file without using Pandas and add new columns and print and output file

Tags: python

I am new to python coding and due to some issue, I need to reconfigure my code without pandas.

I am reading an Excel and extracting a few columns with filtered values. Then passing the one column value to a function to fetch the results. The result comes back in a complex dictionary format then I have to create a new column from the dictionary then join the two outputs (initial Excel file and complex dictionary) and print that back in the output file.

So my data is

```
Customer         Customer Name          Serial Number
 1                XYZ                    101011
 2                XYZ                    1020123
 3                XYX                    102344
```

Dictionary output

```
[{'cert': {'alternate_names': [],
           'created_on': '2017-09-10T16:15:25.7599734Z',
           'csr_used': False,
           'error_details': '',
           'revocation_date': None,
           'revocation_status': None,
           'serial_no': '101011',
           'status': 'Expired',
           'valid_to': '2020-09-09T23:59:59.0000000Z'},
  'meta': {'api_application_biz_unit': '',
           'api_client_nuid': '',
           'asset_name': '',
           'audience': 'External',
           'automation_utility': '',
           'delegate_owner': '',
           'environment': 'Development',
           'l2_group_email': None,
           'l3_group_email': None,
           'requestor_email': '',
           'support_email': '',
           'tech_delegate_email': None,
           'tech_owner_email': None}}]
```

Desired output:

```
Customer        Customer Name     Serial Number    Alternate_name  Audience  Environment
 1               XYZ               101011           []              External  Dev
```

My Code:

```
def create_excel(filename):
    data = pd.read_excel(filename, usecols=[4,18,19,20,26,27,28])
    data["Customer Name"].fillna("N/A",inplace= True)
    df = data[data['Customer Name'].str.contains("XYZ",case = False)]
    output = df['Serial Number'].apply(lambda x: fetch_by_ser_no(x))
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(output)
    df2.columns = ['Output']
    df5 = pd.concat([df,df2],axis = 1)
    df3 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(x)) for x in df2['Output']],
                    ignore_index=False)
    df3["Serial Number"] = df3.iloc[:,11]
    df4 = pd.merge(left = df5, right = df3, how = 'left',
                   left_on = df5["Serial Number"].str.lower(),
                   right_on = df3["Serial Number"].str.lower())
    df4.fillna("N/A",inplace = True)
    df4["Status"] = df4.iloc[:,21].replace({"N/A":"Cust Not Found"},inplace = True)
    df4["Status"] = df4.iloc[:,21]
    df4["Serial Number"] = df4.iloc[:,4]
    df4["Audience"] = df4.iloc[:,30]
    df4["Environment"] = df4.iloc[:,33]

    df4[["Customer","Customer Name","Serial Number","Common Name","Status",
         "Environment","Audience"]].to_excel(r'Data.xlsx', index = False)
```

I want to remove the pandas dependency from the code. I am having a hard time figuring this out.

Comment: Not exacly an answer, but you can try to use `pprint` for a better readability of your data. That might be helpful for debugging big dicts.

Comment: You will need to use a third-party module to read native Excel files — there are number of them available. The Python standard library can only read CSV files.

Comment: please help anyone? I can read the excel file using openpyxl but how to disintegrate the complex dictionary into columns and then join the excel columns and complex dictionary columns into one output without pandas and then print into excel file is somewhere I am getting stuck.  I don't know how can I move out of pandas.

Comment: Please help !!!